# When do I lose my unregistered account?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

When I login as anonymous, (well it sounds weird, but logged in with email only in SO, or as a guest)

What causes me to lose that account? (not being able to post something as the user)

closing down the tab that has the Stack Overflow page?

Comment: Hi. Please don't (ab)use `code blocks` (backticks) in text. For more see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: "Anonymous identity" really got me confused

Comment: @hims056: will do so, thought it was a standard practice in SO, since it makes the text the most visible.

Comment: Yeah, I tried creating an account with an email address, and I couldn't find it afterwards.  I suggest that you try creating an account with OpenID.  It's much easier to manage.

Comment: @Robert: I'm trying to understand how it works. An anonymous user can post many answers and later decide to register it. He might find out he can't login as the "anonymous user" he used.  It's good for an anonymous user to know what causes him to his 'anonymous identity'

Comment: Backticks are used to format **code**. Use of them for **code** is standard practice on Stack Overflow. That is *all* that they are for. Use bold or italics for emphasis if the word is not **code**.